# Nested Variable with ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I would like to create two variables. The first determines whether a person is happy or not. If the person answers with 1 he/she is happy, if with 0 he/she is unhappy. For this I have already created this command in R.

```
    Happy <- ifelse(data$happy == "1", 1, 0)
```

Now I would like to find out, when the person answers with 0, if this has to do with the relationship status. I would like to create a dummy variable again, but in such a way that those who answered 1 in the first question are excluded.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What about `Unhappy <- abs(Happy - 1)`?

Comment: What should this new variable contain if happy ==  0?

Comment: (Also, your code doesn't currently create a new column to your dataset - it creates a standalone vector. You need `data$` at the start if you want to create a new column: `data$Happy <- ifelse(data$happy == "1", 1, 0)`.)